# VBA copy row height

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a backup copy with VBA. The problem is, that everything except the row height is being copied. I tried looking for an answer, but couldnt find anything that fits.

Here's my code:

```
Application.Workbooks.Add                           ' Neue Mappe erstellen

Dim counter As Integer
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim shtOld, shtNew As Worksheet
Dim pfad As String
Dim name As String

pfad = ThisWorkbook.Path
name = Left(ThisWorkbook.name, Len(ThisWorkbook.name) - 5)
'MsgBox "Aktueller Pfad: " & ThisWorkbook.Path
'MsgBox Left(ThisWorkbook.name, Len(ThisWorkbook.name) - 5)

Set wbNew = Application.Workbooks(Application.Workbooks.Count)
Do While wbNew.Worksheets.Count < ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    wbNew.Worksheets.Add                            ' Weitere Tabellen hinzufügen, falls nötig
Loop
' Tabellen kopieren

For counter = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Set shtOld = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(counter)   ' Quelltabelle
    Set shtNew = wbNew.Worksheets(counter)          ' Zieltabelle
    shtNew.name = shtOld.name                       ' Tabellenname übernehmen

    shtOld.UsedRange.Copy                           ' Quelldaten und -format kopieren

    shtNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=8        ' Spaltenbreite übernehmen
    shtNew.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues     ' Werte einfügen
    shtNew.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats    ' Format übernehmen


Next
wbNew.SaveAs pfad & "\" & name & " " & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD hhmm") & ".xlsx"


Application.CutCopyMode = False      ' Zwischenspeicher löschen
```

'

Anyone got an idea? Would be great!

Comment: @Veve taking the row heights is his intention. Usually xlPasteFormats does this which would fit his requirements, except it doesn't in this case which is odd. Perhaps merged cells or text wrapping is over-riding the functionality?

Comment: my recommendation would not to use the copy/paste function, but the worksheet move function, with a copy. This is one I use personally:

    `For Each sheet In Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets
        Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy after:=Workbooks("Main Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets("Information")
    Next sheet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to assign the height, rather than copy/paste formatting.  The code below should get you started:

```
Sub RowHeight()
    Dim wsOne As Worksheet: Set wsOne = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim wsTwo As Worksheet: Set wsTwo = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim RowHght As Long

    RowHght = wsOne.Range("A1").EntireRow.Height
    wsTwo.Range("A1:A10").RowHeight = RowHght
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly then you are trying to save thisWorkBook with a new name as a backup.  This code should do it a little more efficiently.

```
Sub saveCopyOfThisWorkBookWithNewName()
Dim fileFrmt As Long, oldFileName As String, newFileName As String


fileFrmt = ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat
oldFileName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
newFileName = Left(oldFileName, InStrRev(oldFileName, ".") - 1) & "_" & CStr(Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD hhmm"))
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=newFileName & ".xlsx"


End Sub
```

Comment: Or you can actually do it with a single line of code like this: ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=Left(ThisWorkbook.FullName, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".") - 1) & "_" & CStr(Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD hhmm")) & ".xlsx"

Answer (score 0):

You need to select, copy and paste the rows to get the row heights to paste across